# Issue with c# quick sort algorithm

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sorting

I have created two functions that sorts a list using bubble sort, but I would like to change the sort style to quick sort.

I found this quick sort algorithm

http://snipd.net/quicksort-in-c

These are my two functions:

```
    protected void sort_by_section_name()
    {
        int num1, num2;
        for (var i = section_names.Count - 1; i > 0; i -= 1)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j += 1)
            {
                num1 = get_number_from_section(section_names[j]);
                num2 = get_number_from_section(section_names[j + 1]);
                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    swap_list_strings(section_names, j, j + 1);
                    swap_object_items(item_group_list, j, j + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void sort_items()
    {
        int num1, num2;
        List<SPListItem> temp;
        for (var k = 0; k < item_group_list.Count; k += 1)
        {
            temp = (List<SPListItem>)item_group_list[k];
            for (var i = temp.Count - 1; i > 0; i -= 1)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < i; j += 1)
                {
                    num1 = Convert.ToInt32((temp[j])[ORDER_BY_COLUMN]);
                    num2 = Convert.ToInt32((temp[j + 1])[ORDER_BY_COLUMN]);
                    if (num1 > num2)
                    {
                        swap_list_items(temp, j, j + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For sort_items, its an array of arrays, so the bubble sort stuff is in a for loop.

I don't understand how to change these two functions into using the quicksort.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you realise the .NET framework has quicksort built in? Or is this for homework?

Comment: Outside of an academic environment you almost never need to write your own sort algorithm.  Just use whatever the language's library uses unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: Blah blah, reinventing the wheel.

Comment: the problem is the items in the array are SPListItems, and it needs to sort based on an attribute of the item. If I directly compare the item object it won't work. I need to extract the attribute value then compare those values as seen in my current bubble sort functions above.

Comment: @ Chris S. => this isn't homework, I just dont understand how to compare it and the reason why is in the above comment by me.

Comment: @omega You shouldn't be re-implementing your own sort algorithm every time you want to sort using some custom comparer.  You should be asking "How do I sort this collection with data of this type based on this comparison criteria?"  We can then provide you with the best answer, which, in this case, will involve a library function doing the actual sorting.

Comment: Omega - you get a lot of sorting built into .NET so you don't have to worry about writing your own. It's interesting to try to implement a bubble sort from a learning perspective, but if you just "want it to work" then the answer below should help.

Comment: Ditto to all the other comments about wheels.  You just need to implement a custom `IComparer<T>` or pass in a `Comparison<T>` delegate into `List<T>.Sort` e.g. want to sort a list of strings based on their length: `list.Sort((x,y)=>x.Length - y.Length);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a `List<SPListItem>` and you want them sorted, using an efficient sorting algorithm (aka not bubblesort) based on the numeric value of some field.  This is easy, and doesn't involve you re-implementing quicksort.

```
List<SPListItem> list = ...;

var sortedData = list.OrderBy(item => Convert.ToInt32(item["fieldName"]));
```

It's also worth noting that when possible it's usually better to sort your data on the database, rather than on the webserver.  You should be able to add an `Order By` clause to the CAML query generating those `SPListItem`s and let it do the sort.

It appears that you're sorting two different data structures that are "parallel" (the item at the same index of both structures "belong" together).  This is generally undesirable.  While there are ways to perform a sort on both structures, what you really should be doing is making a single structure such that each item holds onto everything that logically represents that one item.  In many cases this means creating a new `class` that has properties for each piece of data.  You can then populate a collection of this new composite class and sort that.

Comment: when I tried this, it says List<string> doesn't have a method .Orderby

Comment: You need to add `using System.Linq` as this uses an extension method from within that namespace.  You also need to be on C# 3.5+.  There are ways to do this from C# 1.0 that don't involve writing your own sort, but this is the shortest/most readable code.

Comment: I tried this `section_names = section_names.OrderBy(item => get_number_from_section(   item[SECTION_COLUMN].ToString()     ));` but it getting an error, invalid argument. What is the item variable? Where is it defined?

Comment: `item => item` is a "lambda", which means that it's a function that takes a parameter named 'item' and returns whatever is on the right hand side of the `=>`.  The compiler is smart enough to infer it's Type based on context.  It essentially means, "for each item in the list, use this function to get something (an int here) out of this SPListItem and use that as the sorting metric".  As for the error, it it seems that the function you're using doesn't take just a string, or it doesn't return any value.

Comment: nvm my last comment, the section_names is a List<string> where each of  it's strings begin with a number, and it needs to sort based on that. So now I tried `section_names = section_names.OrderBy(item => get_number_from_section(   item     ));` but i am getting a cast error, so i think i need to cast somewhere. But the other issue is, there is another array that needs to be in sync with this, i.e. when ever two things gets swaped it needs to occur with the other array as seen in my bubble sort code in the top.

Comment: @omega It won't return a `List`, it will return a `IEnumerable`.  If you need a list then just add `ToList` to the end of it.  If you don't actually need a list then just store it in a new variable that is of the proper type.

Comment: also if I have a list and I want it sorted, do I need to do `x = x.OrderBy...` or just `x.OrderBy...` ?

Comment: @omega `OrderBy` doesn't sort (or change in any way) the underlying `List`, it returns a new sequence of items based on some other collection.  If you don't set the result to a variable then you haven't really done anything productive.

Comment: so if I set section_names to the new list, then GC will dispose of the list that was used before?

Comment: @omega Probably, unless that old list is referenced somewhere else.  In any case, you shouldn't really think about garbage collection much.  It's very good at doing it's job all on its own.  When you are dealing with one of those rare programs that actually consumes a LOT of memory (enough to potentially run out) then it's worth thinking about it a bit.

Comment: thanks, your idea of creating a new class of combining all the data is very useful idea. Plus using the Orderby method on it is genius.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write it yourself in .NET - you can use:

1. [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a basic array of items
2. LINQ - [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) for example with a `List<string>` (make sure you have using System.Linq at the top of the class)
3. If you're feeling adventurous, look into [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx)
4. Use myItems.Sort() which sorts them in place.

For what you want, the easiest way to get started is using #2, here's an example:

```
List<SPListItem> myItems = GetSomeItems();
myItems = myItems.OrderBy(i => i["MyField"]).ToList();

foreach (var item in sortedItems)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Without knowing the fields you're after, or much about the Sharepoint object that's a bit of a guess, there's are about 5 different ways of doing it in .NET with comparable interfaces (some more info [here](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/9/27/icomparable-icomparer-equals-iequatablelttgt-iequalitycompar.html)). As you can't change the SPListItem class then Sort or LINQ maybe easiest.

Comment: so to use this in my example, what do I replace item with?

Comment: @omega can you post the definition of `SPListItem`

Comment: @ChrisS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx It's for dealing with SharePoint.  Queries return collections of SPListItems.

Comment: yes, but I did what Servy said it's now a lot easier to manage.